# simple linq issue, but I can't figure it out

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a simple LINQ issue. I'm trying to query a list and match a member ID with a lists ID and then return some text:

```
var IDtext = IDMethod(MembID);
var t = from ctext in cIDtext 
        where ctext.cid.ToString() == MembID 
        select cxt.C_ID;
ViewBag.thisID = t.ToString();
```

All this returns is:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[pu15.Models.C_ID,System.Int32]
```

But this never changes or shows what I want it to show.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb155325%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342451%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535050%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [`FirstOrDefault`](http://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fvstudio%2Fbb340482(v%3Dvs.100).aspx&ei=dgxiVKL7C4WO7AbyhIDAAg&usg=AFQjCNFDYA_7ijHWKddGK9gG8kMHzDl-jw&bvm=bv.79189006,d.ZGU), depending on what you want exactly, e.g.:

```
ViewBag.thisID = t.Single();
```

- `Single` will throw an exception if there is more than one result or if there are no results.
- If you'll use `SingleOrDefault` instead it will return `null` in case of more than one result or no result.
- `First` on the other hand will fail only for an empty collection - when there is more than one element it will return the first one.
- The most tolerant, `FirstOrDefault` will return `null` for empty result list, and the first element if there is more than one.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remember that a `where` clause returns an `IEnumerable<T>` and not just one value. You have to take the first or a specific element of that collection and show it or if it is a collection of objects, show a property from that element.

In your case this would be:

```
var IDtext = IDMethod(MembID);
var allIDs = from ctext in cIDtext 
        where ctext.cid.ToString() == MembID 
        select cxt.C_ID;
var single = allIDs.SingleOrDefault();
//or:
var first = allIDs.FirstOrDefault();

ViewBag.thisID = single.ToString();
//or
ViewBag.thisID = first.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use method syntax, skip the `Where` clause, and just use `First()`

```
ViewBag.thisID = cIDtext
                  .First(c => c.cid.ToString() == MembID)
                  .C_ID.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

`t` is an IEnumerable that may return many items. If you only want to use one of these items, you need to call `t.First()` or `t.Single()` ,eg:

```
 ViewBag.thisID = t.First().ToString();
```

The difference between the two methods is that `Single` will throw an exception if there are more than 1 items in the results, while `First` will only throw if there are no matching results.

If you want to check that a result actually exists, you can use `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault`, eg:

```
 var id=t.FirstOrDefault();
 if (id!=null)
     ViewBag.thisID = id.ToString();
```

You can condense the call if you pass the condition as the predicate to `First`, `FirstDefault` etc:

```
var id=cIDtext.FirstOrDefault(ctext=> ctext.cid.ToString() == MembID);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `t` is an `IEnumerable` and `ToString` will just give you the name of the type.  You need to turn your enumeration into something like a comma separated list

```
ViewBag.thisID = string.Join(",", t.Select(v => v.ToString()));
```

Or more likely you only want one value and you need to use either `First` or `Single`.

```
ViewBag.thisID = t.First().ToString();
```

or

```
ViewBag.thisID = t.Single().ToString();
```

Use `First` if there are multiple return values and you only want the first, or you can use `Last` if you wan the last one.  If the query should return only one value then you should use `Single`.  There are also `FirstOrDefault`, `LastOrDefault`, and `SingleOrDefault` that will return a default value if the enumeration is empty or in the case of `Single` if the enumeration has more than one value.  `Single`, `First`, and `Last` will throw an exception if the enumeration is empty or in the case of `Single` if the enumeration has more than one value.  Just choose the appropriate one for your use case.